# How to get each letter and add them as points with a substring method

Tags: java

I've been trying to create an algorithm where each letter adds points. I don't want to use charAt, I'd like to use the substring method.

My problem is that String letter does not seem to get each letter and the result is always 0.

Is there a way to get each letter and convert it to points?

```
public class WDLPoints{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String word = "LDWWL";
        System.out.println(getMatchPoints(word));
    }
    public static int getMatchPoints(String word) {
        int points = 0;
        String letter = word.substring(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if (letter.equals("W")) {
            points+=3;
        }
        else if (letter.equals("D")) {
            points+=1;
        }
        else {
            points = 0;
        }
        }
        return points;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you printed what this `String letter = word.substring(5);` returns? `System.out.println("letter: " + letter);`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be extracting the text for the letter variable from within the for loop, using the loop index?

Comment: Why don't you want to use 'charAt'? And what do you expect the value of `letter` to be throughout your iteration (hint: it won't change)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following changes in your `public static int getMatchPoints(String word)` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    String letter = word.substring(i, i + 1);
    if (letter.equals("W")) {
        points+=3;
    }
    else if (letter.equals("D")) {
        points+=1;
    }
}
```

`word.substring(i, i + 1)` will get a single letter word and will help you compute your score the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it really simple you can just use `String.toCharArray()` and then iterate over the array of `char` and check its value:

```
public static int getMatchPoints(String word) {
    int points = 0;
    char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
    for (char letter : arr) {
        if (letter == 'W') {
            points += 3;
        }
        else if (letter == 'D') {
            points += 1;
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

I also removed your `else` statement because that was just setting the value to `0` if there is any other letter in the loop.  I think you intended it to be `points += 0` which does nothing, so it can just be removed.

**Example Run:**

Input:

> String word = "LDWWL";

Output:

> 7

**Note:**  I am aware you might not be *allowed* to use this solution, but I thought it would be good info on the possibilities since it does not *technically* use `charAt()`

Also I'd like to point out you misunderstand what `substring(5)` does. This will return all characters after the position of `5` as a single `String`, it does *not* separate the `String` into different characters or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You will find that your variable letter is always the empty String. Here's a better way of doing things:

```
class WDLPoints
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String word = "LDWWL";
    System.out.println(getMatchPoints(word));
  }
  // We have only one method to encode character values, all in one place
  public static int getValueForChar(int c)
  {
    switch((char)c)
    {
      case 'W': return 3;
      case 'D': return 1;
      default: return 0; //all non-'W's and non-'D's are worth nothing
    }
  }

  public static int getMatchPoints(String word)
  {
    // for all the characters in the word
    return word.chars()
    // get their integer values
      .map(WDLPoints::getValueForChar)
    // and sum all the values
      .sum();
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, nor do I think it should be since it answers the question well/correctly, but it does seem a bit over-engineered for the question.

Comment: For the purpose of readability and extensibility (to other characters), this would be a simple and elegant solution. Otherwise, each new character is another if statement.

Comment: Yeah I agree it is a nice solution, I just meant it is complicated for a clear beginner, here I'll even it to 0 for ya

Comment: That's fair. I'd say @MdJohirulIslam's approach is the most pertinent as per the asker's preference for the String::substring method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string represents a football teams performance of the last 5 games, you could keep it simple and readable with something like:

```
public static int getMatchPoints(String word) {
    String converted = word.replace('W', '3').replace('D', '1').replace('L', '0');
    return converted.chars().map(Character::getNumericValue).sum();
}
```

This converts your example input "LDWWL" to "01330" and sums each char by getting its numeric value.